# how to pass two NSAarray to One UIPickerView Based on UITextFields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsarray, uipickerview

I did when I click  when `textField` ,Open `UIPickerView` and then select PickerView Data it's display on `UITextField`.
But now i Have 3 text_Filed(city,typeofcars,branches) but I don't know about three TextFileds on Single `UIPickerView`. So Please give me any idea .

single text-Filed one `UIPickerview` code is:-

```
Businessname=[[UITextField alloc]init];
    Businessname.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 221, 33);
    Businessname.placeholder=@"Business Name";
    [Businessname setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:13]];
    Businessname.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [Businessname setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleBezel];
   Businessname.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
   Businessname.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor yellowColor]CGColor];
   Businessname.layer.borderWidth= 2.0f;
    Businessname.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [scrol addSubview:Businessname];
   yourpicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 100, 150)];
    [yourpicker setDataSource: self];
    [yourpicker setDelegate: self];
    yourpicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    Businessname.inputView = yourpicker;
    [yourpicker  setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];

mypickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 100, 56)];
       mypickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
 [mypickerToolbar sizeToFit];


    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked)];

    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];
    [mypickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    Businessname.inputAccessoryView = mypickerToolbar;

-(void)pickerDoneClicked

{
    NSLog(@"Done Clicked");
     [Businessname resignFirstResponder];
    mypickerToolbar.hidden=YES;
    yourpicker.hidden=YES;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [pickarray count];
}
```

Above code is output is when I click text-filed and then open `UIPIckerView` and then choose the data. But now I have three `TextFields` and 3 NSArrays on Please how to pass data data to `UIPickerView` based on `UITextField`.
So please give me any idea about my problem

Thanks in Advanced

Comment: Maybe if you simplify your code example, by getting rid of irrelevant code to this question, we'll be able to answer you more quickly

Comment: What about add a tag for each `UITextField`? Then you check it before and load the data based on the field tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting tag value for each textfield. Also set delegate of UITextField for each textfield. 
In delegate method of **UITextField**

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

recongnize textfield by it's tag value.
Based on tag value do something like

// Assumed taht 100, 101, 102 is the tag values for textfield's

```
NSInteger tag = textField.tag;

switch(tag)
{
  case 100:
     pickarray = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4"];
     break;
  case 101:
     pickarray = @[@"10",@"20",@"30",@"40"];
     break;
  case 102:
     pickarray = @[@"11",@"21",@"31",@"41"];
     break;
  default: 
     break;

}
```

by this you can assign different values to "pickarray" according to selected textfield and reload your UIPickerView.